# When to use celui vs cela vs ça?

Tags: pronoms, démonstratifs

All the other pronouns have been blissfully clear, but these ones just never clicked for me. They all seem the same to me, I can't keep them straight.

Under what circumstances are they used? Examples would be great!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Celui** est un pronom démonstratif  masculin, féminin *celle*.

> « - Puis-je t'emprunter un livre ?
>      - Avec plaisir, dis-moi celui que tu veux. »
>
> « - Tu pourrais pas me donner une de tes voitures ?
>     - Pas de problème, dis-moi celle que tu choisis. »

On les emploie fréquemment en composition avec une des particules *ci* ou *là*.

> « Ils sont tous très jolis, mais je préfère quand-même  celui-ci ».

En général **ci** s'emploie pour ce qui est proche (dans le temps ou dans l'espace) et **là** pour ce qui est éloigné.

En ancien français on employait aussi le pronom démonstratif **ce**  qui n'est plus guère employé de nos jours.  À partir du XV ème siècle (selon la grammaire Larousse du français contemporain) on l'a surtout employé en composition avec les particules *ci* ou *là*, et ça a donné **ceci** et **cela** en un seul mot. À noter que l'accent grave du *a* a disparu dans la manœuvre.

**Cela** et **ça**, ainsi que **ceci**, sont des pronoms démonstratifs neutres, pas de pluriel, on les emploiera dans les cas où on ne peut identifier ni masculin, ni féminin.

> « - La terre est ronde.
>     - Ah ? c'est la première fois qu'on me dit ça. »

Et pour finir une [page](http://french.chass.utoronto.ca/fre180/Monstra.html#pronoms) de grammaire qui en dira plus.